# How to check for watch mode in webpack.config.js?

Tags: webpack, watch

In my `webpack.config.ts`, I export *two* configurations.

```js
export default [development, production]
```

However, when I run `webpack watch`, the `production` config is rebuilt, and I'd like to avoid that.

How can I watch for only one of the two exported configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Export a function](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function)

```js
export default (env, argv) => [development, production]
```

2. [Check for `env.WEBPACK_WATCH`](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options)

```js
export default (env: { WEBPACK_WATCH: boolean }) =>
  env.WEBPACK_WATCH ? development : [development, production]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [webpack command line environment option --env](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/).

For example:
You can create 2 commands in scripts in package.json file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --env development",
    "build": "webpack --env production"
}
```

And in webpack.config.js file you can access them as follows:

```js
module.exports = (env) => {
    // ...
    watch: env === 'development';
};
```